# numba typeerror on higher dimensional structured numpy datatypes

Tags: python, numba

The following code compiles and executes correctly:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

Particle = np.dtype([ ('position', 'f4'), ('velocity', 'f4')])

arr = np.zeros(2, dtype=Particle)

@njit
def f(x):
    x[0]['position'] = x[1]['position'] + x[1]['velocity'] * 0.2 + 1.
    
f(arr)
```

However, making the datatype more highly dimensional causes this code to fail when compiling (but works without `@njit`):

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

Particle = np.dtype([
            ('position', 'f4', (2,)),
            ('velocity', 'f4', (2,))
          ])

arr = np.zeros(2, dtype=Particle)

@njit
def f(x):
    x[0]['position'] = x[1]['position'] + x[1]['velocity'] * 0.2 + 1.
    
f(arr)
```

With the following error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(Record(position[type=nestedarray(float32, (2,));offset=0],velocity[type=nestedarray(float32, (2,));offset=8];16;False), Literal[str](position), array(float64, 1d, C))
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
    - Of which 16 did not match due to:
    Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
      With argument(s): '(Record(position[type=nestedarray(float32, (2,));offset=0],velocity[type=nestedarray(float32, (2,));offset=8];16;False), unicode_type, array(float64, 1d, C))':
     No match.

During: typing of staticsetitem at /tmp/ipykernel_21235/2952285515.py (13)

File "../../../../tmp/ipykernel_21235/2952285515.py", line 13:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Any thoughts on how to remedy the later one? I would like to use more highly dimensionalized datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `[:]` to set values of the array:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

Particle = np.dtype([("position", "f4", (2,)), ("velocity", "f4", (2,))])

arr = np.zeros(2, dtype=Particle)


@njit
def f(x):
    pos_0 = x[0]["position"]
    pos_0[:] = x[1]["position"] + x[1]["velocity"] * 0.2 + 1.0

    #x[0]["position"][:] = ... works too

f(arr)
print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[([1., 1.], [0., 0.]) ([0., 0.], [0., 0.])]
```